# Yank both sides of equation

Tags: regular-expression, functions, macro, filetype-tex, register

While writing in latex I often want to copy a math equation's right hand side or left hand side. For example I have something like this

```
\begin{gather*}
    5 \cdot \left( A A 3 \right) + 50 \cdot \left( A A 3 \right) = 6CAB \\
    500A + 50A + 15 + 5000A + 500A + 150 = 6000 + 100C + 10A + 5
\end{gather*}
```

and I'd like to copy the right and left hand side of the n-th last equation I've written and store them each in the l and r register respectively. For example if I were to use this on the 2nd last equation the l register would contain

```
5 \cdot \left( A A 3 \right) + 50 \cdot \left( A A 3 \right)
```

and the r register would contain

```
 6CAB \\
```

So far I have this regex which represents a line that has an = between text

```
[^=]*\s\+=\s\+[^;]*
```

But I have no clue on how to somehow input what it's matching into registers and how to find the n-th last equation either... I was wondering if anyone could help me figure this out and was also wondering if this should be a macro?

Answer (score 7):

This can be done with either regex+substitute or macros

**Substitute.**  This is the same as your regex except the important parts are surrounded by `\( . \)` to create capture groups.  These are referred to by `submatch(1)` and `submatch(2)` respectively.  We use the replace expression `\=` and `execute('let')` idiom.  Finally, use `/n` to prevent substitution from actually happening.

```
s/\([^=]*\)\s\+=\s\+\([^;]*\)/\=execute('let [@l,@r]=[submatch(1),submatch(2)]')/n
```

**Macro.**  Create a macro as follows:

```
:let @q = '_"lyt=f=l"ry$'
```

Then type @q to execute the macro on the line.  The parts are:

1. `_` go to start of line.
2. `"lyt=` yank until `=` into register `l`.
3. `f=l` go one past the `=`.
4. `"ry$` yank until end.

**Command.**  Alternatively, this is straightforward to do using basic vimscript

```
:let [@l,@r] = split(getline('.'), '=')
```